# Numerical evaluation of KL divergence for SDE

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, numerical-integration

Consider the SDE

$$
dX_t = v(X_t)dt + dW_t
$$

where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. Girsanov's theorem tells us that the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measure $\mathbb{P}_v$ of $X_t$ with respect to the measure $\mathbb{P}_0$ of $W_t$ is

$$
  \frac{d\mathbb{P}_v}{d\mathbb{P}_0}=\exp\left(\int v(X_t)dX_t - \frac{1}{2}\int |v(X_t)|^2 dt\right).
$$

This allows the computation of the Kullback–Leibler divergence from

$$
D_{\text{KL}}\left(\mathbb{P}_v \middle\| \mathbb{P}_v\right) = \operatorname{E}_{\mathbb{P}_v} \left[\log\left(\frac{d\mathbb{P}_v}{d\mathbb{P}_v}\right)\right].
$$

I think a default approach to a numerical evaluation of the KL would be via a Monte Carlo estimate from a numerical integration of the SDE. I'd like to know:

> Are there numerical schemes that specifically target the calculation of RN derivative or KL divergence?